# XSLT. How to do 2 changes for 1 element? Ordering and renaming

Tags: xslt

I need to change order of elements. But also rename elements into elements.
So, 
I have xml:

```
<transactionality>
                  <rollbackexttransactionid>
                     <rollbackvalidity>3600</rollbackvalidity>
                     <rollbackscheduledattemps>3</rollbackscheduledattemps>
                     <manualcorrectionpath>TransactionalityLogs</manualcorrectionpath>
                  </rollbackexttransactionid>
                  <transactionalitylogspath>TransactionalityLogs</transactionalitylogspath>
                  <rollbacklifecycleevents>
                     <rollbacklifecycle>1200</rollbacklifecycle>
                     <rollbackscheduledattemps>2</rollbackscheduledattemps>
                     <manualcorrectionpath>TransactionalityLogs</manualcorrectionpath>
                  </rollbacklifecycleevents>
                  <rollbackpayment>
                     <rollbackvalidity>1200</rollbackvalidity>
                     <rollbackscheduledattemps>2</rollbackscheduledattemps>
                     <manualcorrectionpath>TransactionalityLogs</manualcorrectionpath>
                  </rollbackpayment>
               </transactionality>
```

1. I need to do element transactionalitylogspath as first in to transactionality.
2. Rename all elements "rollbackscheduledattemps" to "rollbackscheduledattempts"
3. Rename rollbacklifecycleevents/rollbacklifecycle to rollbacklifecycleevents/rollbackvalidity

I would'like to have:

```
<transactionality>
                  <transactionalitylogspath>TransactionalityLogs</transactionalitylogspath>
                  <rollbackexttransactionid>
                     <rollbackvalidity>3600</rollbackvalidity>
                     <rollbackscheduledattempts>3</rollbackscheduledattempts>
                     <manualcorrectionpath>TransactionalityLogs</manualcorrectionpath>
                  </rollbackexttransactionid>
                  <rollbacklifecycleevents>
                      <rollbackvalidity>1200</rollbackvalidity>
                      <rollbackscheduledattempts>2</rollbackscheduledattempts>
                     <manualcorrectionpath>TransactionalityLogs</manualcorrectionpath>
                  </rollbacklifecycleevents>
                  <rollbackpayment>
                     <rollbackvalidity>1200</rollbackvalidity>
                      <rollbackscheduledattempts>2</rollbackscheduledattempts>
                     <manualcorrectionpath>TransactionalityLogs</manualcorrectionpath>
                  </rollbackpayment>
               </transactionality>
```

I did:

```
<xsl:template match="transactionality">
    <xsl:variable name="elements-after" select="rollbackexttransactionid|rollbacklifecycleevents|rollbackpayment"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="transactionalitylogspath"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$elements-after">
        </xsl:copy-of >

    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
            <xsl:template match="rollbackscheduledattemps">
                <rollbackscheduledattempts>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
                </rollbackscheduledattempts>
            </xsl:template>
```

byt it doesn't work :(.
Help me please.

Comment: Please post a complete stylesheet - esp. the part that shows which version of XSLT you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="transactionality">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="transactionalitylogspath"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[local-name() != 'transactionalitylogspath']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="rollbackscheduledattemps">
      <rollbackscheduledattempts>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </rollbackscheduledattempts>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="rollbacklifecycleevents/rollbacklifecycle">
      <rollbackvalidity>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </rollbackvalidity>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's a working example : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6pS26mL